# Factorizing a matrix into a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive semi-definite matrix.

Then, what are some well-known factorization methods that guarantee $W=A^T A$, with the conditions being that

\begin{align}
1.& \ \ \ \ \ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \\
2.& \ \ \ \ \ \text{$A$ has the same rank as $W$}?
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to factor a general positive semidefinite matrix that way.

$A^TA$ is automatically symmetric. But there are positive semidefinite matrices that are not symmetric. Like $W=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\newline-1&1\end{bmatrix}$, which has $\vec{v}^tW\vec{v}=(v_1+v_2)^2\geq0$ for all $\vec{v}$.

Did you intend to ask about factoring a symmetric matrix? Or a Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such a decomposition for all p.s.d. matrices $W$. But take a look at [Matrix decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) especially [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

Cholesky factorization with pivoting. See [Higham, Cholesky Factorization](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1199/), the section "Semidefinite Matrices".