# When can a matrix $A$ be factored into a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

When can a square matrix $A$ be written in the form $A = B^T B$ ?

What I understand is *Every Hermitian positive-definite matrix (and thus also every real-valued symmetric positive-definite matrix) has a unique Cholesky decomposition* : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

In what and all situations ($A$ need not be Hermitian positive-definite) this factorization is possible?

Means if $A = B^T B$ is true for what all $A$. One condition is for Hermitian positive-definite matrices. What are the other conditions?

Related : [Factorizing a matrix into a matrix and its transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438307/factorizing-a-matrix-into-a-matrix-and-its-transpose)

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix with real entries? If not, is $B^T$ the transpose or the conjugate transpose?

Comment: If it's a matrix with real entries, the answer is the set of symmetric positive semi-definite matrices.

Comment: If it's a matrix with complex entries and $T$ denotes the entrywise transpose, then the answer is all symmetric matrices.